# Creating CFArray from MySQL Result Array

Tags: php, mysql

Is there an easy way to dump an array returned from mysql_fetch_row into a CFArray? (part of the PHP implementation of [CFPropertyList](https://github.com/rodneyrehm/CFPropertyList))
I'm bummed by the lack of documentation on CFPropertyList for PHP.
Iterating through each item in the array seems inefficient. I'm open to using a different mysql_fetch_... command.

I'd like to just say:

```
$NewArray = new CFArray( $ResultArray )
```

But that deosn't seem to work.

This is my current code:

```
$plist = new CFPropertyList();
$ResultRow = mysqli_fetch_row( $result );
$plist->add( $TableRow = new CFArray() );

foreach ( $ResultRow as $Item ){
    $TableRow->add( new CFString( $Item ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some new functions of [CPPropertyList](https://github.com/rodneyrehm/CFPropertyList) that should make this pretty easy. Namely `CFTypeDetector`.
Here's a new version of the code in the question. (This code is untested).

```
$Plist = new CFPropertyList();
$TD = new CFTypeDetector();

while ( $ResultRow = mysqli_fetch_row($Result) ){
    $GuessedStructure = $TD->toCFType( $ResultRow );
    $Plist->add( $GuessedStructure );
}
```